# Displaying 1 text box and 3 images on the same row

Tags: css, html, row

Was wondering if i can display 1 text box and 3 images on the same row? All the images are the same size. If possible aswell i'd ideally like a some text underneath each image aswell?

heres the code:

```
      <div class="row">
    <div class="side-bar">
        <h3> Recent Work </h3>
        <p>Here's some of my latest work, covering web design, branding and identity.</p>
        <a href="#">View the Portfolio &rarr;</a>
    </div>

<div class="recent-wrap">
    <a href="#"><img src="img/body-metrix.png"></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="img/body-metrix-logo.png"></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="img/market.png"></a>
</div>
</div>



.row {
    display: inline;
    float: left;
}
.side-bar {

    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #f3f3f3;
    height: 200px;
    width: 250px;
}

.side-bar h3 {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 19px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.side-bar p {
    font-size: 14px;

}

.side-bar a {
    font-size: 13px;
}


.recent-wrap img {
max-width: 225px;
min-height: 125px;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 1px;
border-color: #000000;
margin-right: 20px;
margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

Ive searched the internet but no luck as yet.
thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have any specific browser requirements such as IE7 or whatever?

Comment: I believe you are looking for `display:inline-block` or `float: left`

Answer (score 7):

There are a number of ways to do this, one example is to float the two child elements:

```
.side-bar, .recent-wrap {
    float: left;
}
```

This will only work if there is enough room on the parent element for the `.side-bar` and `.recent-wrap` to sit next to each other.

Example: http://jsbin.com/poxox/1/edit

Comment: I always always always prefer display: inline-block over float, but both work.

Comment: Thats works, thank you. Just one more thing, how can I add text underneath each image?

Comment: @user3087394,  when adding the text you're gonig to see why float can be a nightmare

Comment: @ScottSelby `float` is always the best

Comment: @ScottSelby So how can I achieve this

Comment: @ScottSelby floats require proper `clear`ing. With any tool, you'll need to know _how_ to use it..

Comment: @user3087394 Add text if you like. I prefer kittens though.

Comment: @CarrieKendall, true of course ,  but when someone is on here asking a question of this type you can assume their level at CSS , and instead of spending some time reading up on float and clearing you can simply use inline-block

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 .side-bar {
     padding: 10px;
     background-color: #f3f3f3;
     height: 200px;
     width: 250px;
     float: left;       /* added */
 }

 .recent-wrap {
     margin-left: 270px;        /* added (padding + width) of side-bar */
 }
```

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KrfEb/3/)**

This approach let the second container stay in line with the first container even if the window size is small.

Comment: I had first suggested with `display: table-cell` which is not at all a good one to go with because the elements lose control on heights..

Answer (score 0):

CSS:

```
.row {
   width: 250px
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3DCSd/

Answer (score 0):

[Here Is a working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Gh58Z/)

```
.row {
    display: inline-block; /* changed to inline-block, you don't need
                              inline and float */       
}   

.recent-wrap a {   /*changed to a , since your images are wrapped in <a> */
max-width: 225px;
min-height: 125px;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 1px;
border-color: #000000;
margin-right: 20px;
margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

The rest of the CSS stayed the same

and HTML I just added the text box

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="side-bar">
       <h3> Recent Work </h3>
       <p>Here's some of my latest work, covering web design, branding and identity.</p>
       <a href="#">View the Portfolio &rarr;</a>
   </div>

   <div class="recent-wrap">
     <input type="text" id="ss" />
     <a href="#"><img src="img/body-metrix.png"/></a>
     <a href="#"><img src="img/body-metrix-logo.png"/></a>
     <a href="#"><img src="img/market.png"/></a>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the sample with textboxes below image: [example](http://jsbin.com/jokufewi/1/)